# How do I switch multiple div layers using a interval service loop in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

**Ok, I would like to switch multiple div layers every 8 seconds, using a interval service loop. Each div layer should show every 8 seconds starting from div1 and ending with div4, then loops back to div1.Here is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="" />

<title>Untitled 2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-animate.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="bgApp">
    This should change every 8 seconds!
    <div id="view" ng-controller="switchDiv" >
   <div ng-show="view" >
   <div ng-show="div1" > This is Div 1!</div>
   <div ng-show="div2" > This is Div 2!</div>
   <div ng-show="div3" > This is Div 3!</div>
   <div ng-show="div4" > This is Div 4!</div>
   </div>

   </div>
   <script>
   var app = angular.module('bgApp', ['ngAnimate']);
   app.controller('switchDiv', function($scope, $interval) {
   $scope.view =  new Div();
   $scope.view = $scope.div1;
   $scope.view = $scope.div2;
   $scope.view = $scope.div3;
   $scope.view = $scope.div4 ;

   $interval(function () {
   $scope.view = new Div();
   }, 8000);
   });</script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

**thanks in advance,
Batoe**

Comment: Do you understand what ng-show does?

Comment: ng-show displays the div layer an ng-hide removes the div layer from the view. I want toshow different div layers based on a specific time interval. I am still new to Angularjs and the conditional syntax is something I need to work on. php is much easier but it is back end. Angular is more appropriate for what I plan to do.

Comment: It shows or hides an element based on a boolean condition. in your case `div1`, `div2`, etc. are the boolean conditions. But you never initialize those to anything. Hint. use a counter. Each time the interval function is called, do `counter = (counter + 1) % 4`. Show div1 if the value of the counter is 0, div2 if it's 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you might be a little confused about what scope does. Consider scope just a giant container for data you want your HTML to see. Ng-show takes a boolean, so since you never initialized $scope.div1 to anything, it considers that false and therefore does not show. Try initializing $scope.div1 to true in your controller and you should see what I mean. That should help you in the right direction.

Comment: Well I am still not successful at the div switch conditional syntax. here is my code:     app.controller('switchDiv', function($scope, $interval) {
    
    $scope.div1 = true; 
    $scope.div2 = false;
    $scope.div3 = false;
    $scope.div4 = false;
    
    newDiv function(){
   $scope.div1 = true;
   }
   newDiv function(){
   $scope.div2= true;
   }
   newDiv function(){
   $scope.div3= true;
   }
   newDiv function(){
   $scope.div4 = true;
  }
  $interval(function () {
      $scope.view = newDiv function($scope);
  }, 8000);
return.view

Comment: I need to see sample syntax for this type of process.

Comment: I would probably create a counter, i =1. In my interval check if i is >8, If so set to 1. Then say $scope["div"+i] =true.